# Create contraption: regenerating floor block toggle

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

How do I create a system that does the following when pulsed:

1. Switches a block from the floor with a stone block
2. Waits for a couple seconds, wherein the block is destroyed by a player
3. Puts the original floor block back
4. Replaces the empty space where the stone was destroyed with another stone block from a generator.

I've tried using simple stone generator and block switcher mechanisms, but they always replace the empty space where the stone was with a piston head. Is there a different block switcher that doesn't do that, or is there a better way to create the same effect?

Comment: Do you have the option of command blocks?

Comment: No, no op. Otherwise, placeblock would work.

Answer (score -1):

Just have the generator close but not part of the swapper. At least one block should be "ready" to be insert into the swapper at the right time instead of hoping that the generator creates a new block in time. Since lava/water generate stone based a little bit on random ticks you can't rely on that timing, but if you have the block ready and then the generator will be able to replace it during the time the rest of the contraption is working.

Answer (score -3):

try using a repeating command block with a setblock command with the proper coordinates. (warning: does not replace it with different blocks, only replaces it with one, so it wont regenerate as the normal block)

Comment: p.s. use this command to get a command block, then turn it into a repeating one manually: /give @p minecraft:command_block

Comment: The OP has said that he cannot use commands.